# remplazar texto de un array con la funcion map

Tags: javascript

no entiendo porque no puedo remplazar el texto pero si puedo mostrarlo

```html
<p id="poesia">
    LA SCARPETTA
    Mi sa che ieri sera eri di fretta
    guarda che ti sei persa la scarpetta.
    io stamattina l’ho trovata
    con la carrozza ieri sei scappata.
    E’ stato bello insieme a te danzare
    il Cuore tu mi hai fatto sussultare,
    </p>
    <button onclick="iterare()">iterar</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      texto = document.getElementById('poesia').textContent
      
      lineas = texto.split(/\n/) // division x saltos de lineas
      
      function iterare(){
        lineas.map(function(elemento, indice){
          if(indice % 2 == 0){
            console.log(elemento)
            /*
            "Mi sa che ieri sera eri di fretta"
     "io stamattina l’ho trovata"
    "E’ stato bello insieme a te danzare"
            */
            lineas[indice].replace(elemento, 'lineas')
          }
        })
      }
      //undefined
    </script>
```

Comment: Para reemplazar puede intentar con `lineas[indice] = lineas[indice].replace(elemento, 'lineas');`

Answer (score 2):

Cuando ejecutas el replace, efectivamente remplaza un texto por el otro, pero no haces nada con el, en este ejemplo lo concatene en un nuevo texto, con el cual lleno el elemento con el id 'poesia'

```js
function iterare(){
    
    texto = document.getElementById('poesia').textContent
    lineas = texto.split(/\n/) // division x saltos de lineas
    res=""
    lineas.map(function(elemento, indice){
      if(indice % 2 == 0){
        console.log(elemento)
        res+=lineas[indice].replace(elemento, " Lineas ")
      }else{
        res+=lineas[indice]
      }
    })
    console.log(res)
    document.getElementById('poesia').innerHTML=res
  }
  //undefined
```

```html
<p id="poesia">
LA SCARPETTA
Mi sa che ieri sera eri di fretta
guarda che ti sei persa la scarpetta.
io stamattina l’ho trovata
con la carrozza ieri sei scappata.
E’ stato bello insieme a te danzare
il Cuore tu mi hai fatto sussultare,
</p>
<button onclick="iterare()">iterar</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

la función `.replace`, no actúa sobre el String, sino que devuelve un String con el resultado del reemplazo, por lo cual lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
lineas[indice] = lineas[indice].replace(elemento, 'lineas')
```

[Aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) te dejo el ejemplo y el modo de usar de W3School

También te dejo por [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/t0kbytzc(v=vs.94).aspx) la documentación de MSDN

Answer (score 2):

Se hace el llamado a la función `replace` que retorna un `String` más no es asignado al indice y elemento actual del `map`dentro del array , para resolver esto, debe asignar al indice de la forma.

```
lineas[indice] = lineas[indice].replace(elemento, 'lineas');
```

Lo que plantea puede darse si retornará otro arreglo.

```js
texto = document.getElementById('poesia').textContent
  lineas = texto.split(/\n/) // division x saltos de lineas
  function iterare(){
    var neww = lineas.map(function(elemento, indice){
      if(indice % 2 == 0) return lineas[indice].replace(elemento, 'lineas');
      else return lineas[indice];
    })
    console.log(neww);
  }
```

```html
<p id="poesia">
LA SCARPETTA
Mi sa che ieri sera eri di fretta
guarda che ti sei persa la scarpetta.
io stamattina l’ho trovata
con la carrozza ieri sei scappata.
E’ stato bello insieme a te danzare
il Cuore tu mi hai fatto sussultare,
</p>
<button onclick="iterare()">iterar</button>
```